# A two-colouring of a complete graph over the set of incompressible strings

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

A two-coloring is done over the (infinite) set all incompressible strings (in some chosen alphabet); such that, an edge between two strings is blue if and only if, the strings are of equal lengths and the conditional Kolmogorov complexity of one, given the other is at least as much as the string length .

The edge is coloured red otherwise.

Now, a blue clique here signifies a set of strings of same length each of which contain no algorithmic information about the rest.

It is easy to see that there are infinitely many blue cliques. Note that there cannot be an infinite blue clique due to the string size constraint.(Also, if it matters here, there will be an infinite red clique)

The question we set for ourselves is regarding the clique size  for a clique with a given string length.

**Are there infinitely many blue cliques with at least  as many strings as the string length?**

A more general way to put it would be:

**Are there infinitely many blue cliques with  size of at least $O(n)$ strings, where $n$ is the string length?**

Comment: Given the third paragraph, "zero" in the first paragraph should say "at least the length of the string". But most strings are incompressible relative to any given finite string, so the expected answer would be that there are $p_0 > 0$ and $n_0$ such for $n \ge n_0$ a random set of $n$ incompressible strings of length $n$ would be a blue clique with probability greater than $p_0$. Further refinement of the argument would depend on the exact model of computation: e.g. do you have random access to the characters of the parameter string?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ammended the first para, thanks.We do not use any randomized models.